# 0x API Help: Order Routing

Tags: 0x

Our project is working to integrate order routing for the trading feature on our application, and we are exploring using the 0x API for this purpose.

The design of our system is such that we intend to route orders exclusively through a specific network of pools across a number of DEXes which are powered by users of our system.

Using the 0x API, is it possible to only route orders through a specific set of pools rather than all of the available liquidity sources?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer on this. We love 0x.

Best,

CP

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to route orders through specific pools at this time with the 0x API.

You can exclude liquidity sources with the `excludedSources` query parameter (e.g. `excludedSources=Uniswap`) in order to keep certain liquidity providers from being included in the quote returned by the 0x API, but this functionality does not currently extend to specific pools.

Thanks for your interest in the 0x API. 0x loves you too!

Comment: Hi Megan! Thanks for your response. Sorry for beating this topic too much, one more Q to confirm. Is it possible to use the whitelist feature here for this: https://0x.org/docs/guides/0x-extensions-explained#whitelist-contract 

https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/blob/69025da2dcb4bded72cbf724c598ee09682d2dfc/contracts/exchange/contracts/examples/Whitelist.sol#L27

Comment: #0x Hi @Megan ! Thanks for your response. Sorry for beating this topic too much, one more Q to confirm. Is it possible to use the whitelist feature here for this: 0x.org/docs/guides/0x-extensions-explained#whitelist-contract https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/blob/69025da2dcb4bded72cbf724c598ee09682d2dfc/contracts/exchange/contracts/examples/Whitelist.sol#L27

Comment: Hey there CP! That whitelist feature has been deprecated, so while it is still possible to use it please keep in mind that we no longer maintain it and you do so at your own risk. Please also keep in mind that this feature was only for limit orders filled through [meta transactions](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/advanced/mtx.html). Hope this helps :)